# RestFul cucumber acceptance test to get local file json as output

Tags: json, rest, restful-url, resttemplate

I want to mock a resttemplate output. We have a service */someservice/getJson* to get json. To mock this service we kept a json file in the code base and tried to get it to the response entity as follows.
 
*working code:*

```
String baseURL = "http://localhost:1010"
String uri = /someservice/getJson
ResponseEntity<T> entity = restTemplate.exchange(baseURL + uri, GET, new HttpEntity<>(headers), type);
```

I have a json file in the code base (say codebase/../resource/myfile.json)
I would like to get the response entity as the local json I mock.
I tried using exchange method. It doesnt seems as working for me.

*What I tried with my json file*

```
String localJson = "/resource/myfile.json";
ResponseEntity<T> entity = restTemplate.exchange(localJson, GET, new HttpEntity<>(headers), type);
```

I think there are another methods to get it done other than *exchange*. But I am not aware of those. 
Is there any other way / is there any mistake in what I tried ?

Comment: What do you expect the mock to return? `ResponseEntity` or JSON converted to a Java object?

Comment: yes a JSON object.

Answer (score 0):

To read a file with JSON object and convert it into a POJO you can use `ObjectMapper`’s 
`readValue(File src, Class<T> valueType)` method ([readValue doc link](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.2.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html#readValue%28java.io.File,%20java.lang.Class%29)) from `Jackson` framework:

```
import java.io.File;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
YourJsonType response = mapper.readValue( new File("file with JSON object")  , YourJsonType.class);
```